# Please help me identify this UK plant

Tags: identification, outdoor

This has been growing in my vegetable patch and I am not sure what it is.

[image: What is this?]
[image]
[image]

This structure is growing at the end of a 30cm stem and there are a few of them growing quite close together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have been better to see a photo of the whole plant, but judging by what's there, its a Euphorbia of some variety. These are often difficult to dig out, because the roots can go down quite a way. Confirmation of it as a Euphorbia is if it produces white sap when you break a stem - that sap can be highly irritant on some people's skin, so wear gloves when handling this plant.

There are hundreds of varieties of this plant available for purchase, but also many that pop up as weeds, or have been deliberately planted and are persistent despite attempts at removal. Example of a similar one here: [Euphorbia microsphaera Boiss.](http://flora.org.il/en/plants/EUPMIC/)

Comment: Thanks, I have added additional photos.  It does have a white sap and I think that you are probably right, it may have grown back from an unsuccessful attempt to remove it.

Comment: Definitely Euphorbia, and in my experience, this one's a pain to try to get rid of - takes persistence!

Comment: Got it in my eyes once- I washed my hands as you do and then I went for my face- driving home my eyes just stung like hell! and using eye wash made them sting more! so my advice is make sure you wash your hands thoroughly! with soap if possible- but the plant you show here is looking very healthy! are you sure you want to get rid of it- some euphorbias are very nice indeed.